# Android: Find contacts from the address

Tags: android

How can i find the contacts associated with a particular address? For example: I want to search for all of my contacts who live at "1st Main road". I tried searching via

```
Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI
```

but it didnt work. It was throwing "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid lookup id".

Comment: Address of the contact is in "Data" table. So You have to use ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI for finding the contact_Id and then you can pass that id in Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI

Comment: you can review this website also for different use of contact in android. http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. Here is how i did it:

```
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { Data._ID, Data.DISPLAY_NAME, Data.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI }, Data.DATA4 + "=?" + " AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",new String[] { String.valueOf(streetAddress }, null);
```

And by using this cursor, we can find the name, photo or whatever we want.

```
if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
    String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    String imageUri = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI));
}
```